# Submartingality of generalized stochastic exponential of a BMO martingale

Tags: probability-theory, martingales, bmo-martingales

I attended a talk today on BMO martingales. It was my first encounter with the subject, and this may explain my inability to solve this myself.

We take a continuous local martingale $L$, and say that $L\in BMO$ if

$E[\langle L\rangle_{\infty}-\langle L\rangle_T|\mathcal{F}_T]\leq C$

for any stopping time $T$ and an absolute constant $C$. We define then

$G_t^L(\alpha)=\exp\left(\alpha L_t+\left(\frac12-\alpha\right)\langle L\rangle_t\right)$        $\qquad (0\leq t<\infty)$.

Now comes the problem. He wrote down that

$E[G_t^L(\alpha)|\mathcal{F}_T]\geq G_T^L(\alpha)$, for some $\alpha\neq 1$

called it trivial and moved on in his agenda. In other words, we need that

$E\left[ \exp\left( \alpha L_t+\left.\left( \frac12-\alpha\right)\langle L\rangle_t\right)\right| \mathcal{F}_T\right]\geq \exp\left(\alpha L_T+\left(\frac12-\alpha\right)\langle L\rangle_T\right)$.

What immediately comes to my mind with submartingality is to use the Jensen inequality. This gets me next to nowhere.  Obviously, I need to apply some property of the BMO martingale to get there, but every result I find on the subject (John-Nirenberg inequality, reverse Hölder inequality, etc.) pulls me in the wrong direction, so to speak. I have also tried seeking help in texts on analysis (Muckenhoupt, Fefferman...) but to no avail. With the lecturer noting that the result is trivial, I suspect it's just me making this problem more complicated than it really is.

Now, corollary 6 in [this article](http://www.oxford-man.ox.ac.uk/~jruf/papers/quadVariation.pdf) combined with theorem 6 of [this article](http://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.tmj/1178229055) leads me to believe that his claim may well be true, but I can neither prove it myself nor find a reference on it. Is it common knowledge that $G$ would be a submartingale in this case, or is it just me overlooking something.

Comment: Forgive me for bumping this up. I have added some thoughts and hopefully made the question more clear for anyone willing to give it a go.

Comment: What does this notation $<L>_T$ mean?

Comment: @BoZenKhaa, $\langle L\rangle$ is the quadratic variation of the local BMO martingale $L$. You may also have seen it written as $\langle L,L\rangle$.

Comment: Oh i see, I know it as square brackets, $[L]=[L,L]$.

Comment: Is it possible you copied it wrong, and it should be $G_t^L(\alpha)=\exp\left(\alpha L_t-\frac12\alpha^2\langle L\rangle_t\right)$?

Comment: Then maybe you could use an argument similar to that used to prove Hoeffding's inequality.

Comment: But $\frac12 \alpha^2 \ge \alpha - 1/2$, and so maybe that will make it work.

Comment: No, I don't think this works.  Sorry.  If it did work, the inequality would go the other way.  The idea was to prove it for dyadic martingales (which is all I really understand), and use the inequality $\cosh(x) \le \exp(\tfrac12 x^2)$.

Comment: Or maybe you had another typo and got the inequality the wrong way around.

Comment: @StephenMontgomery-Smith, no, trust me. I thought that was the case for the longest of times, but I've talked to a few people who took notes at the lecture, and they've confirmed it's what he wrote. Moreover, the corollary, due to J. Ruf, that I linked to above all but confirms that submartingality is what we're looking for.

Comment: Did you ask the person who gave the talk?  It seems to me that if one tries the very simplest discrete time martingale, namely on the first step it takes the values $\pm d$ each with probability $1/2$, then the argument I provided gives precisely the opposite inequality.

Comment: Just a minute - your process is continuous.  So maybe you can use $\cosh(x) = \exp(x^2/2) + O(x^4)$ to show **equality** if $G(\alpha)$ is replaced by what I wrote several comments ago.  Then to get the inequality, use $\frac12 \alpha^2 \ge \alpha - \frac12$.